# How to reolve error gradle sync failed the library being requested by various other libraries?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

I wanted to implement firestore in my project but after adding the following line my gradle sync is failing

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.2'
```

and i am getting the error

```
Gradle sync failed: The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.1,15.0.1]], but resolves to 16.0.1. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.
        Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

what is this error and how to resolve it 
also the classpath I am using is

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
```

Comment: Can I see your dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

downgrade the used library to the version shown in console. That is

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:15.0.1'
```

This happens due to conflicting versions

Comment: thanks that worked but if i want to use latest version how do i do that ?

Comment: I get this error too, and as of the present this solution works for me.
The latest versions currently don't offer any specific new functionalities in my experience. Not all new libraries are released with the latest version simultaneously, and in the in-between transition time, this is how to go by.  Although it's a good practice to used the latest versions, that should not be of much concern in the present

Answer (score 0):

Check this gradle file for project level

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

 buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.30'
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check this one, I just created for particular issue never **tested**

```
 configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.google.firebase') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("firebase-firestore")) {
                details.useVersion '17.1.2'
            }
        }

    }
}
```

add this one in `defaultConfig` tag in app gradle file